# Dropdown terminal toggle key for text entry

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

Dropdown terminal binds this key '`' (the key above the tab key; backtick) with its launch. Whenever I press this key, it launches dropdown terminal or closes it. How can I use this key to input the assigned character (backtick) in a text or in the terminal?

Comment: What is "Dropdown terminal"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are talking about [the Gnome extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/442/drop-down-terminal/), I assume? That extension uses "the key above the tab key" by default, whichever character that may correspond to in your specific keyboard layout.

According to [this issue](https://github.com/zzrough/gs-extensions-drop-down-terminal/issues/66) in the extension's issue tracker, it doesn't provide a way to type the character that's "blocked" by the shortcut. But you can change the shortcut key in the extension's settings, for example to CTRL-`.

Comment: assigning a key combo with `back tick`. this way seems you can use `back tick` and `~` both the symbols as usual in a text editor or terminal..